# How to use BufDelete and BufWipeout when the deleted/wipeout buffer differs from %?

Tags: vimscript

Consider the following script:

```
vim9script

var buffer_info = getbufinfo()

g:buflist = []
for dd in getbufinfo()
    add(g:buflist, dd['bufnr'])
endfor

def g:BufListRemove()
  # If the buffer is in the buffer list, then remove it.
  var idx = index(g:buflist, bufnr())
  if idx != -1
    remove(g:buflist, idx)
  endif
enddef

augroup myaugroup
    autocmd BufDelete,BufWipeout * g:BufListRemove()
augroup END
```

Say that I have 4 buffers opened, numbered from `1` to `4`. Hence, `echo g:buflist` (after having run the above script) returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, which is fine.

Say now that the current buffer is `4` and I run `:bw`. Then, `echo g:buflist` correctly returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

The problem arise when the wiped out (or deleted) buffer is not `%`.

Foe example, If the current buffer is `3` and I run `:bw1`, then `echo g:buflist` returns `[1, 2]`.

Inspection of the documentation of `BufWipeout` (same for `BufDelete`) say that

```
NOTE:           When this autocommand is executed, the
                current buffer "%" may be different from the
                buffer being deleted "<afile>".
                Don't change to another buffer, it will cause
                problems.
```

But then I have no idea on how to circumnavigate this note.

What I want is that if I run e.g. `:bw1` , then the item 1 is removed from `g:buflist` and not the current buffer.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Try using `expand('<afile>')`

Comment: … almost. I had to  str2nr(expand(‘<abuf>’) instead of bufnr(). That solved.

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to replace the line:

```
var idx = index(g:buflist, bufnr())
```

with the line:

```
var idx = index(g:buflist, str2nr(expand('<abuf>'))
```

See `:h <abuf>` and `:h expand()` for more information.